# sqlalchemy MySQL connection read large result set into dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy connection to a MySQL database. I would like to query the database and return a pandas dataframe, around 7M rows:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

con = create_engine('[mysql connection]')

df = pd.read_sql("""
SELECT 
T1.COLUMN1, 
T2.COLUMN2 
FROM TABLE1 T1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 
ON T1.COLUMN3 = T2.COLUMN3""", 
con=con)
```

This crashes my kernel. I tried streaming server-side batches, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

con = create_engine('[mysql connection]')

df_gen = pd.read_sql("""
SELECT 
T1.COLUMN1, 
T2.COLUMN2 
FROM TABLE1 T1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 
ON T1.COLUMN3 = T2.COLUMN3""", 
con=con.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True), chunksize=1000000))

result_list = []
for gen in df_gen:
    result_list.append(gen)
df= pd.concat(result_list)
```

But this also crashes my kernel.

Comment: Remove the chunksize paramether (you don´t need it) and you will get on `df_gen` a Dataframe, don´t need to iterate over the DF to create a list for then concat the list into a DF again

Comment: What will the steam_results parameter do in this case?